# XML data transformation Problem using XSLT

Tags: xslt

My Input File is:

```
<product>
   <a001>12345</a001>
   <a002>02</a002>
   <a197>College</a197>
   <b207>College-Higher Educational</b207>
   <othertext>
      <d102>01</d102>
      <d103>02</d103>
      <d104>Some Data</d104>
   </othertext>
   <othertext>
      <d102>02</d102>
      <d103>02</d103>
      <d104>Some Data</d104>
   </othertext>
   <othertext>
      <d102>04</d102>
      <d103>02</d103>
      <d104>Some Data</d104>
   </othertext>
</product>
```

From above input file I want to transform data to following output data:

If <d102> is 01 then replace it with <x426> 03

If <d102> is 02 then replace it with <x426> 02

If <d102> is 04 then replace it with <x426> 04

Desired Output Data is:

```
<product>
   <a001>12345</a001>
   <a002>02</a002>
   <a197>College</a197>
   <b207>College-Higher Educational</b207>
   <collateraldetails>
         <textcontent>
            <x426>03</x426>
            <x427>00</x427>
            <d104>Some Data</d104>
         </textcontent>
         <textcontent>
            <x426>02</x426>
            <x427>00</x427>
            <d104>Some Data</d104>
         </textcontent>
         <textcontent>
            <x426>04</x426>
            <x427>00</x427>
            <d104>Some Data</d104>
         </textcontent>
      </collateraldetails>
      <contentdetails>
         <contentitem>
            <b288>Main Title</b288>
         </contentitem>
      </contentdetails>
      </product>
```

What I have tried is

```
<xsl:template match="product/othertext">
    <xsl:element name="collateraldetail"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="othertext">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="d102[text()=01]">
                <xsl:element name="textcontent">
                    <xsl:element name="x426">03</xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="x427">00</xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="d104">
                        <xsl:value-of select="d104"/
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="d102[text()=02]">
                    <xsl:element name="textcontent">
                        <xsl:element name="x426">02</xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="x427">00</xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="d104">
                            <xsl:value-of select="d104"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="d102[text()=04]">
                    <xsl:element name="textcontent">
                        <xsl:element name="x426">04</xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="x427">00</xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="d104">
                            <xsl:value-of select="d104"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:element name="contentdetails">
                <xsl:element name="contentitem">
                    <xsl:element name="b288">Main Title</xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
```

I am not able to get desired output from this code. If I wrap all <othertext> in some parent tag, then I get desired output but not in current scenario.

Comment: 1. What if `d102` has some other value? 2. Which version of XSLT does your processor support?

Comment: Your output has `x427` instead of `d103` - but you didn't say anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::othertext)]"/>
        <collateraldetails>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="othertext"/>
        </collateraldetails>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="othertext">
    <textcontent>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </textcontent>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d102">
    <x426>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".='01'">03</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=".='02'">02</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=".='04'">04</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </x426>
    <x427>00</x427>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d103"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But your output shows other changes for which you did not provide any explanation or logic.